# How to convert result set row into columnn

Tags: mysql

I am getting a result set like this

```
user_id
57
83
71
40
96
58
99
27
```

Now I want to store this eight rows into eight columns so can anybody tell me how to convert the rows into columns

Comment: @MURTUZA007 :these 8 rows are fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

```
 SELECT
    if(user_id=57, 57, '') as user57,
    if(user_id=57, 83, '') as user83,
    if(user_id=57, 71, '') as user71,
    if(user_id=57, 40, '') as user40,
    if(user_id=57, 96, '') as user96,
    if(user_id=57, 58, '') as user58,
    if(user_id=57, 99, '') as user99,
    if(user_id=57, 27, '') as user27,
    FORM tablename
```

Assuming your rows are fix.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pivot table.

Here is a link to a tutorial on how to pivot in MySQL: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78

There are a lot of questions/answers on SO about this subject as well.